# Sync the zoho crm with sql database using c# code

Tags: c#, zoho

I am new to ZohoCrm.

Instead of passing the hardcoded data from c# to zoho CRM, I need to pass the data from the database table to Zoho. Then I need to synchronize both the database and update it to CRM

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.zoho.com/crm/help/api/

> Zoho CRM provides API (Application Programming Interface) for
>   integrating CRM modules with third-party applications such as,
>   accounting, ERP, e-commerce, self-service portals and others. With the
>   Zoho CRM API, you can extract CRM data in XML or JSON format and
>   develop new applications or integrate with your existing business
>   applications. As the Zoho CRM API is independent of programming
>   languages, you can develop applications in any programming language
>   (Java, .Net, C, C++, PHP, etc.).

.NET client for interacting with Zoho CRM service https://github.com/deveel/zohocrmsharp.

Your work is the custom logic for "pass the data from data base table to Zoho"